# How could iterate over this specific data (dict inside a list which is the second value of a tuple inside another list) in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How could I take the below collection and iterate over it in a
django template ?

```
[('Foo Key', [{'lname': 'Bar', 'fname': 'Foo'}])]
```

Please note the above example is much smaller just to keep things simple. 
If we need the fully expanded collection, e.g if size matters, I can update this post.

My closest successful attempt is noted below.

```
{% for key0, value0 in data %}
    <tr>
        <td> key0 {{ key0 }}:</td>
        <td> value0 {{ value0 }} </td>
    </tr>

    <p> {% for value1 in value0 %}
        <td> {{ value1 }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </p>

{% endfor %}
```

and this will leave me with the below output.

Foo Key {'lname': 'Bar', 'fname': 'Foo'}

I cannot seem to get 'Bar' or 'Foo' out of it.

Some other context 
Here is the view where the data is produced

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Person, PersonMeta    

# Create your views here.
def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'thanks.html')    


from .forms import NameForm


def home(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            data = {}
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            currentUser = request.user
            person = Person.objects.create(first_name=currentUser.first_name, last_name=currentUser.last_name,
                                           nickname=form.cleaned_data['nickname'])
            # getting front loaded personMeta
            personDetails = PersonMeta.objects.filter(frontLoaded_first_name=currentUser.first_name,frontLoaded_last_name=currentUser.last_name).values()

            # setting key
            currUserKey = "{0} {1}".format(currentUser.first_name, currentUser.last_name)

            # if person details is not false
            # this if may not have to be here. 
            if (personDetails):
                data[currUserKey] = personDetails    

                # redirect to a new URL:
        return render(request, 'signUp.html', {'data': sorted(data.items())})    

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    #
    else:
        form = NameForm()    

        return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `dict` inside a `list` which is the second value of a `tuple` inside another `list`:

```
[('Foo Key', [{'lname': 'Bar', 'fname': 'Foo'}])]
```

So here we go:

```
{% for tuple in data %}
    <p>Tuple key: {{ tuple.0 }}</p>
    {% for key, value in tuple.1.0.items %}
        <p>Dict key, value: {{ key }}: {{ value }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. That this solves the issue. I need to read up on tuple for loops. I would like to know more about what this line ` {% for key, value in tuple.1.0.items %}` is doing.

Comment: You're welcome. Dots are used for indexing in Django template language. The line you asked is simply the equivalent of `for key, value in tuple[1][0].items:` in Python.